# How do those who are not using a backend framework (such as Rails/Symfony/Django) go about developing and deploying an Ember application's assets?

Tags: ember.js, single-page-application

More specifically, when using a backend application framework I generally am afforded some level of asset management which allows me to work with multiple files in development which are uncompressed and unminified and then in production mode those files become automatically minified, compressed, and concatenated into a single file.

I am looking to create an Ember application that is a single page app that interfaces with a separate RESTful services layer. I simply do not need the weight of a framework behind the Ember app and am hoping to serve it as static html+css+js, so I am looking for any guidance on how to easily manage development and deployment of a client-side only app without adding much overhead.

Right now my biggest issue is with including JS (and to a lesser extent, CSS) files. My HTML is static and I have an Ember app comprised of many files, so I have many script tags to include them all. This is clearly not appropriate for production so I imagine some kind of build tool will be needed to assemble my Javascript files and overwrite the script tags in the HTML file. Are there tools out there right now that will do this? Is there another approach that I may be overlooking?

This is my first fully client-side application so it's very possible that I just need to make a paradigm shift, having done server-side applications for so long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed this can be tricky without a backend framework. For sure script tags are not the way to go and you will need some kind of build tool for production deployment.

[Ember App Kit](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit/wiki/Getting-Started) is a solution a few of us have been working on. It's still early stages but i've used it for a couple of projects so far and it's been much better than trying to roll-my-own with grunt. I would expect it to become the default starting point for ember apps in near future, to try it now just [download it as a zip](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit/archive/master.zip) then read the [Getting Started Guide](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit/wiki/Getting-Started)

There are many other solid solutions out there, consider checking out:

- [ember-tools](https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-tools)
- [brunch-with-ember-reloaded](https://github.com/gcollazo/brunch-with-ember-reloaded)
- [brunch-with-hapmsters](https://github.com/wordofchristian/brunch-with-hampsters)
- [charcoal](http://www.thomasboyt.com/2013/05/02/announcing-charcoal.html)

Comment: From the 5 minutes of playing with Ember App Kit, it seems that this is an all-in-one solution including hosting of the ember application? Is there a way to take advantage of this without hosting the application through it?

Comment: It's not really designed to host the ember app. It does include a sample deploy task that pushes a production build of your app to s3, but that's totally optional.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to imply production hosting. The get started guide shows starting a server and accessing your application that way during development. I am using Vagrant and have a very controlled dev vs production setup where dev is as close to production as I can get ,including nginx as the host for the Ember app. Am I able to take advantage of this without using the grunt server in development or is that part of the magic that I would miss out on?

Comment: The included `grunt server` has very little magic, it's just there to serve the static assets. you wont miss out on anything by using nginx instead.

Answer (score 1):

I use a combination of [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) and [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/), using [these lovely functions](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib) and [this one, which can compile your ember-handlebars templates into functions.](https://github.com/yaymukund/grunt-ember-handlebars) (The [git-contrib](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib) includes the ability to watch for changes in your files and perform various build steps which may differ if you are in development or production. You can have separate grunt functions which run various tasks for production or development. Of course for all of this you are going to need [node!](http://nodejs.org/)